# how return array of image from rest web services

Tags: java, android

iam fresh in android,,
want to return array of image from rest web services ,, i found this
    @GET
    @Produces("image/jpg")
    public Response getFullImage() throws IOException {
        File[]myFile = new File[2];

```
myFile[0]=new File("C:\\Program Files\\test.jpg");
myFile[1]=new File("C:\\Program Files\\test2.jpg");
    BufferedImage image =ImageIO.read(myFile[0]) ;
    image =ImageIO.read(myFile[1]) ;

  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
    byte[] imageData = baos.toByteArray();  
  return Response.ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData)).build();
}
```

but how store array of image into bufferimage in way which can recive in client side and separete between image 
thnx all

Comment: What does the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET
    @Consumes({ MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN, MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces("text/json")
    public Response retrieveClientImage(@PathParam("entityId") final Long userId, @QueryParam("maxWidth") final Integer maxWidth,
            @QueryParam("maxHeight") final Integer maxHeight, @QueryParam("output") final String output) {
        Collection<AdImageData> imageDataResults = this.imageReadPlatformService.retrieveAdImages(userId);
        // TODO: Need a better way of determining image type
        List<String> newfiles = new ArrayList<>();
        String imageDataURISuffix = ContentRepositoryUtils.IMAGE_DATA_URI_SUFFIX.JPEG.getValue();
        for (AdImageData adImageData : imageDataResults) {
            if (StringUtils.endsWith(adImageData.location(), ContentRepositoryUtils.IMAGE_FILE_EXTENSION.GIF.getValue())) {
                imageDataURISuffix = ContentRepositoryUtils.IMAGE_DATA_URI_SUFFIX.GIF.getValue();
            } else if (StringUtils.endsWith(adImageData.location(), ContentRepositoryUtils.IMAGE_FILE_EXTENSION.PNG.getValue())) {
                imageDataURISuffix = ContentRepositoryUtils.IMAGE_DATA_URI_SUFFIX.PNG.getValue();
            }
            final String clientImageAsBase64Text = imageDataURISuffix + Base64.encodeBytes(adImageData.getContentOfSize(null, null));
            newfiles.add(clientImageAsBase64Text);

        }

        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(new Gson().toJson(newfiles)).type("text/json").build();
    }
```

In this example method returns response array of image data, in browser you can iterate and get each object in iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code:

```
        File file = new File("images.jpg");
        String fileName = file.getName();

        response = Response.ok((Object) file);
        response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ fileName);

        return response.build();
```

Comment: Could you please add some descritption?

Comment: Question is on passing an "Array" of images. not one image. please read properly.